# Issues mapping sample editing knobs from Korg volca sample to BeatStep Pro

Tags: midi, korg, midi-controller-drums

I was able to map all of the sample slots on my Korg Volca sample to my BeatStep pro on the drums sequencer midi channels 1-10. I'm having a hard time mapping the knobs of the Volca Sample to the BeatStep pro. I'm trying to be able to change to speed of the sample so I can make a Melody and bass line. I'd like to do it on the BeatStep Pro because I can utilize the 64 steps. I tired following this chart here http://filipe-teixeira.com/electronic-music/volca-resources/volca-sample-tutorial-5-midi-and-external-automation/ I still wasn't able to change to speed while using the drum sequencer after updating. Am I doing something wrong?